# What is the fastest way to turn the phone into silent mode?

Tags: settings, silent-mode

The title kinda tells it all. Sometimes I need to turn silent for a meeting and the procedure is like:

1. Unlock the phone
2. Click on `Menu`
3. Go to `Settings`
4. Click on `Sound`
5. Enable `Silent mode`

Apart from (1), which can't be shortened (can it?), I want to minimize the remaining 4 clicks.

EDIT: I have a Nexus S, but I'm more interested in things that are not specific to models. Also, please feel free to add model-specific answers, as other people may find it useful.

Comment: What phone? On my Nexus One, I can just hit my volume-down button (without unlocking) one click down past vibrate.

Comment: @Uninspired I tried to leave that open so answers can be generic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Personally, I think that the easiest way (apart from sliding right to left, but that's not available on all phones) to put the phone into silent mode is to **hold down the `power button` for a short period of time, then select `Silent mode`**.

Answer (score 8):

It CAN be shortened!

You can silence your phone straight from the lockscreen by **sliding from right to left.**

See this video:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oTQ-c7QJdYQ#at=4m

Comment: +1 This is great! I'm going to accept @Linus's answer because I have a locking pattern so can't use this. Nice to know, though :)

Comment: Doesn't work with HTC sense :-(

Answer (score 4):

Holding the Volume-Down button on most Android devices from the home screen will drop to silent mode.

Answer (score 2):

You can also a widget on your home screen to toggle between silent / vibrate / normal modes.

Too many to list. Most popular ones work well.

Comment: I use [Widgetsoid](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.jim2&feature=search_result)

Answer (score -1):

There is an android app named as Profilo which provides a lot of features to silent your phone quickly. This app has four features location based, voice based, time based and a shake functionality. The quickest way is that shake your mobile once and it will be silent. Shaking again will unmute it. You can schedule your phone as well. You can save a location. At that location your cell phone automatically will be on silent mode. Here is the link.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apptrekkers.profilo

Comment: See [How to not be a spammer](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/promotion)