# Completely "Mute" my Android Phone?

Tags: silent-mode, samsung-galaxy-y, mute

I have seen the Question: [Is there a one-click widget to make my phone completely silent?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13352/is-there-a-one-click-widget-to-make-my-phone-completely-silent) and this is not a Duplicate Question.

In my, Samsung Galaxy Y phone, when I completely reduce my volume, it goes to the "Vibration" mode. Turning the volume down again after the "Vibration" mode appears has no effect in my phone.

I have look around and found no option to mute at all. My Question is whether is it possible to completely mute an Android phone without downloading/installing any extra app?

Doing everything mentioned in: [What is the fastest way to turn the phone into silent mode?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8573/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-turn-the-phone-into-silent-mode?rq=1) puts my phone to "Vibration".

I can't believe that there can exist a phone in today's world without such a basic feature.

Comment: when i turn down the volume all the way on every android device in my house (1 running TouchWiz, 1 running Froyo Stock, 1 running Gingerbread Stock, 1 running Blur, 1 running CyanogenMod 9) it goes to vibrate mode. Then if I turn the volume down again, it goes to complete silent mode. This is probably a duplicate of [What is the fastest way to turn the phone into silent mode?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8573/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-turn-the-phone-into-silent-mode?rq=1)

Comment: @RyanConrad Turning the volume down again after the "Vibration" mode appears has no effect in my phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to your Settings on your phone
2. When in your settings go to "Sound", then "Silent mode and vibrate" and things will pop up
3. Push "Silent mode"
4. Then push "Vibrate", then "Never"
5. Then your phone is all the way off!!

Answer (score 4):

After exploring a little more, I found this solution:

- Click your device "home" button;
- Tap "Settings";
- Tap "Sound";
- Tap "Vibrate";
- Select either "Never" or "Only when not in Silent mode".

That's it!